# How to prevent an asset css file from caching in a custom BE module?

Tags: css, backend, typo3-10.x

I've found this line of code to embed custom css in my custom BE module extension.

`<f:asset.css identifier="myextcss" href="EXT:myExt/Resources/Public/Css/myext.css" />`

This works fine. But the browser caches this file - how do I prevent it from this? I know, that pages can be set non-cache in FE. But in BE I want only this file prevented from caching, not the whole module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some trying I found a workaround.

I add these lines to my controller

```
$mytoken = substr (str_shuffle($_GET['token']),0,8);
$this->view->assign('mytoken', $mytoken);
```

And this to my fluid:

```
<f:asset.css identifier="myextcss" href="EXT:myExt/Resources/Public/Css/myext.css?{mytoken}" />
```

So the browser find always a "new" file request and reload it.